# Can someone verify this identity for switching the order of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Can someone verify that the identity $$\int_a^b \int_x^b f(x,y) \,dy\,dx =\int_a^b\int_a^y f(x,y) \,dx\, dy$$ is true?

For the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2 $ I get the same for both integrals: $$ \int_a^b\int_a^y (x^2+y^2) \, dx\, dy=\int_a^b \int_x^b (x^2+y^2) \, dy\,dx= \frac{1}{3} (a-b)^2 \left(a^2+a b+b^2\right).$$ Thanks!

Comment: The limits of integration can be considered as integrating a rectangle of side $a$ and side $b$. Consider the x- axis being length $a$ and y being that of $b$, now integrate just the component of a line from the origin to the point (a,b) to that of y = b. This is the left-hand side. The area enclosed in that region can be transformed into integration of the same type, ie from x = a to y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

\begin{align}
\int_a^b \int_x^b f(x,y)\,dy\,dx &= \int_a^b \int_a^b f(x,y)\mathbb{1}_{\{x\leq y\}} \,dy\,dx  \\& = \int_a^b \int_a^b  f(x,y)\mathbb{1}_{\{x\leq y\}}\,dx\,dy \\ &= \int_a^b \int_a^y f(x,y) \,dx\,dy
\end{align}

Comment: For posterity: this is assuming some nice properties of $f$ but for OP's purpose, these properties are likely to be tacitly assumed.